# Can't close/hide any folders in Jupyter Lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I needed to clear my file browser in Jupyter Lab because I have too many open folders and i just lost among them.

I couldn't delete or hide any because it's said that they are not empty. Many of them are system like Desktop or Downloads, so i don't want to delete all files there.

[image: View of my file browser]

What u could recommend to do? Or maybe someone had same problem

Answer (score 0):

So solution is simple:

1. Put your notebook in folder u wish
2. Then go to Jupyter Notebook
3. And use File -> "Open from path" -> and get path u need